# Why can’t printf be formatted with an array of ints?

Tags: java

I want to format an output string with a series of variables. When I use an array of strings, this works as expected:

```
String[] myArray = new String[3];
// fill array with strings
System.out.printf("1: %s \n2: %s \n3: %s\n", myArray);
```

I want to use this to print the results of simulated dice-throws, so I use an array of ints. However, this doesn’t work:

```
int[] myArray = new int[3];
// fill array with numbers
System.out.printf("1: %d \n2: %d \n3: %d\n", myArray);
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != [I
```

Of course, I could use `myArray[0]` etc. for every element, but this doesn’t seem very elegant.

Why is this so and how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a loop or something in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`printf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is a [variable argument method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) that takes a `String` (the format string) and an arbitrary number of arguments (to be formatted).

Varargs are implemented as arrays in Java. `printf` expects `Object` as its varargs type, therefore the internal type is `Object[]`.

A `String[]` is-a `Object[]` (i.e. it can be cast to that type), so the elements of the `String[]` will be interpreted as the separate arguments.

An `int[]` however, can't be cast to an `Object[]` so the `int[]` itself will be the first (and only) element of the varargs array.

Then you try to format the `int[]` using `%d` which won't work, because an `int[]` is not a (single) decimal number.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `String` is a reference type (i.e. subclass of `Object`) while `int` is a primitive type. The printf method expects an array of `Object`s (actually variable length argument list), and so a `String[]` fits in fine. Whenever you pass in a `int[]`, since `int` is not an `Object` but `int[]` is, it takes the whole `int[]` as a single object and considers that a single argument.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but String is an object whereas int is not.
`printf` takes an Object array for the parameters.
 
Try `Integer[] myArray` instead.

Answer (score 1):

printf uses variable arguments so that we can pass 0 t0 n arguments to it:

`public PrintString printf(String format, Object... args);`

```
out.printf("%s:%s", a, b);
```

That is the equivalent of:

```
out.printf("%s:%s", new Object[] { a, b });
```

So, getting back to your question, for an array, you can just write:

```
out.printf("%s:%s", things);
```